# how do I parse unwanted character in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a data as follows. I get the data below by this SQL query

> select type from table1 where Type like '%PS%'

Type
32/PS
GS\PS
PS\32
PS\ST
PS32
PSST

now what I want to get from above table is this:

Type
32
GS
32
ST
32
ST

so I need to essentially parsed out PS and "slash" or "dash" symbol

how can I do this in SQL?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
select
replace(replace(replace([type],'/',''),'PS',''),'\','')
from
table1 
where 
[Type] like '%PS%'
```

Answer (score 1):

"parse" isn't the right word, but it looks like a simple replacement would do:

```
SELECT
                      Replace( [type], '/PS', '' )
             Replace(                             , 'PS\', '' )
    Replace(                                                   , 'PS', '' )
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    [type] LIKE '%PS%'
```

Comment: this won't remove the PS without \ or /

Comment: @mucio I've corrected it to remove '`PS`' unconnected to a slash.